# Updating large amounts of data in an EF Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a SQL table with a hundred million rows or so in it, and its schema is managed by EF migrations.

I want to change the values in an enum linked to that table, so i need to update all values in the DB to new values. Something like the below.

```
this.Sql("UPDATE MyTable SET MyEnum=0 WHERE MyEnum=-1");
```

This would be all good on a smaller table but because of the size of the table its not really appropriate to run such a large update in one go (I get connection timeouts, tempdb space issues, transaction logs space issues ect). It would be much preferable to do this in batches. eg:

```
while(ctx.MyTable.Any(m =>m.MyEnum == -1))
{
    this.Sql("UPDATE TOP (1000000) MyTable SET MyEnum=0 WHERE MyEnum=-1");
}
```

Unfortunatly i cant work out a way to read from the table during a migration (eg how can you do this during a migration `ctx.MyTable.Any(m =>m.MyEnum == -1)`). Is there a way to do this so that I can batch in my EF migration update.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation, based on knowing exactly how slow EF would be for you (even when doing it in batches), would be for you to create a Stored Procedure to do exactly what you're wanting to do, and then just have the Migration simply call that Stored Procedure while it's running. It should, hopefully, run through it fast since everything would be done on the SQL side of things.

Comment: I'm already running a raw SQL update (not really EF at all), a SP will be prone to the same problems as it wont complete in the timeout period and will use lots of log/tempdb space while its executing.